# MySQL collation mismatch

Tags: mysql, collation, heidisql

I am running thew following query in mySQL using HeidiSQL :

> select distinct id,title from tablesales where title in (select title
>   from customers).

and I get the following error :

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and
>   (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

I am using HeidiSQL and tried to change the collation of the column in one of the tables but not successful. IS there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be helpful: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,265345,265579

And this: http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-collate-tricky.html